# the status of dev-disk-by-xxx.device jobs still waitting after linux poweron

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, filesystems, mount

I run linux on imx8(NXP CPU),the 1th process is systemd,after login system,execute "systemctl list-jobs" shown some jobs status is waitting.

```
JOB UNIT                                                            TYPE STATE  
241 dev-disk-by\x2did-mmc\x2d88A378_0x11afd0a0\x2dpart4.device      nop  waiting
216 sys-devices-platform…0-mmc0:0001-block-mmcblk0-mmcblk0p1.device nop  waiting
244 sys-devices-platform…0-mmc0:0001-block-mmcblk0-mmcblk0p4.device nop  waiting
215 dev-mmcblk0p1.device                                            nop  waiting
219 dev-disk-by\x2did-mmc\x2d88A378_0x11afd0a0\x2dpart2.device      nop  waiting
218 dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-ab685616\x2d02.device                   nop  waiting
211 dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Boot\x5cx20imx8mq.device                   nop  waiting
236 dev-disk-by\x2did-mmc\x2d88A378_0x11afd0a0.device               nop  waiting
235 dev-disk-by\x2dpath-platform\x2d30b40000.mmc.device             nop  waiting
213 dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5438\x2d0EB3.device                         nop  waiting
240 dev-disk-by\x2duuid-…300\x2d4678\x2db9d4\x2dbe73d205eae9.device nop  waiting
212 dev-disk-by\x2did-mmc\x2d88A378_0x11afd0a0\x2dpart1.device      nop  waiting
221 sys-devices-platform…0-mmc0:0001-block-mmcblk0-mmcblk0p2.device nop  waiting
243 dev-mmcblk0p4.device                                            nop  waiting
237 dev-mmcblk0.device                                              nop  waiting
214 dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-ab685616\x2d01.device                   nop  waiting
220 dev-mmcblk0p2.device                                            nop  waiting
239 dev-disk-by\x2dpath-platform\x2d30b40000.mmc\x2dpart4.device    nop  waiting
242 dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-ab685616\x2d04.device                   nop  waiting
238 sys-devices-platform…c_host-mmc0-mmc0:0001-block-mmcblk0.device nop  waiting
217 dev-disk-by\x2dpath-platform\x2d30b40000.mmc\x2dpart2.device    nop  waiting
210 dev-disk-by\x2dpath-platform\x2d30b40000.mmc\x2dpart1.device    nop  waiting

22 jobs listed.
```

This information appears to be related to the system partition the system partition is

```
root@imx8mqevk:/lib/systemd/system# lsblk --fs
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1  vfat   Boot imx8mq 5438-0EB3
├─mmcblk0p2  ext4               bfc7ccd6-d303-44c5-9466-e6114742d3c7
├─mmcblk0p3  ext4               bfc7ccd6-d303-44c5-9466-e6114742d3c7    1.3G    45% /
└─mmcblk0p4  ext4               c28cc558-0300-4678-b9d4-be73d205eae9    817M     5% /media/usr
mmcblk0boot0
mmcblk0boot1
nvme0n1
└─nvme0n1p1  ext4               eecda9f6-3317-4762-ab05-36b345f19309  413.4G     1% /mnt
root@imx8mqevk:/lib/systemd/system#
```

A special point is that I used two mounts to mount the partition and bind the folder. The one is media-usr.mount

```
[Unit]
Description = mount mmcblk0p4
DefaultDependencies=no
[Mount]
What = /dev/mmcblk0p4
Where = /media/usr
Type = ext4
Options = defaults
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

the other one is etc.mount

```
[Unit]
Description = bind etc dir
DefaultDependencies=no
After=media-usr.mount
[Mount]
What = /media/usr/etc
Where = /etc
Type = none
Options = bind
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

Sometimes the system bootup successfully, and execute "systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg", The content is as follows [image: boot.svg]

What is the cause of this problem and how to fix it